# HTML5 including html page

Tags: html

What is the best way to include html page to another html page? I've tried object and embed tags but no results, don't tell me that this question has been ask because using object or embed tags or even frames or iframes is not a solution!
So is there any way to do that ?

Comment: why iframe is not a solution?

Comment: What kind of include are you talking about?

Comment: I'm trying to include my header and footer instead of copying it in every single page of my site , @laaposto using iframe makes the site load the header and footer as if they were seperate pages

Answer (score 3):

HTML is a **document type**, It isn't a programming language (PHP, Python, Perl...) or server-side technology (ASP.NET, JSP, Servlet). You can't **embed** HTML pages to other HTML page.

Use `<iframe`> tag in HTML. ( tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp )